# Dual Screen PDF Reader

Tags: windows-7, tablet, multiple-monitors, pdf-reader

I've got a tablet with two equal sized screens that runs Windows 7. How can I rotate the screens easily without a button to do it with? A batch file or a utility? One to turn it sideways. Another to turn it back.

Is there any good PDF readers that hand dual screens? One page on screen 1... next page on screen 2. tap one it goes <== that way... tap 2 it goes ==> that way. Most PDF readers I see have the ability to rotate the paper, so I could just do it with a good reader... but I haven't been impressed with Adobe or Foxit.

**Edit:**
Picture of the tablet  [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004P0WLEY)
The goal of course would be to hold it like a book, with a page on each screen.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Searching on Google brought up a previous post from SuperUser with a similar question. Apparantly [Evince](http://live.gnome.org/Evince/Downloads) is worth a try. There is a windows build there.

Comment: I saw that with regards to Linux... didn't know there was a windows build. I'll check it out.\

Comment: Okay, hopefully it works properly, with full features.

Comment: doesnt seem to do the trick. cant get it open on both screens. still tinkering but it doesnt look good (evince looks fine, just not what i want)